# Balanced Tree structure for storing and updating 3D points

Tags: data-structures, kdtree, spatial-query

I'm on an odyssey to find a good tree structure to store and update my application data.

- The data are positions in 3 dimensions (x, y, z)
- They need to be able to be updated and queried by range quickly (every 30 milliseconds). The queries would be, for example: "get all the points around (2,3,4) in a radius of 100cm"
- The data is always in internal memory.

Could someone of you recommend me a good type of tree that meets these requirements?

The KD-Trees wouldn't work for me because they are not made to be updated at this speed. I should rebuild them whole on every update.
BKD-Trees wouldn't work for me either because they are made to store data on disk (not in internal memory).
Apparently the R-Trees are also designed to store the data in the leaves.

Comment: "Apparently the R-Trees are also designed to store the data in the leaves (on disk).". So, since you want to store data on disk, why are you not using R-trees? I think they are the tool for the job (specifically R-Star-trees).

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear enough in the original post. The data is always stored and queried in internal memory, not disk or external storage. My english is not the best.

Answer (score 2):

If you need fast updates as well as range queries, in-memory, I can recommend either a grid index or the PH-tree.

A [grid index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_(spatial_index)) is essentially an 2D/3D array of buckets. The grid is laid over your data space and you just store your data in the bucket (=grid cell) where your point is. For range queries you just check all entries in all buckets that overlap with your query range.
It takes a bit trial and error to find the best grid size.
In my experience this is the best solution in 2D with 1000 points or less. I have no experience with 3D grid indexes.

For larger datasets I recommend the [PH-tree](http://phtree.org) (disclaimer: self advertisement). Updates are much faster than with R-trees, deletion is as fast as insertion. There is no rebalancing (as it happens with R-trees or some kd-trees) so insertion/deletion times are quite predictable (rebalancing is neither need nor possible, imbalance is inherently limited).
Range queries (= window queries) are a bit slower than R-trees, but the difference almost disappears for very small ranges (windows).
It is available in Java and C++.

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I'm needing! I'm glad you introduced me to the PH-tree because I hadn't found it on my own. I'm going to be testing the implementation in C++. Thanks!!